# Is Safari's IndexedDB 50MB limit per domain or total for device?

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, indexeddb

Looking at [Google's IndexedDb documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa), it states that mobile safari's limit is 50MB.

> In mobile Safari, apps can use up to 50MB max

Is this limit for the total of mobile safari (or chrome) app on the iPhone/iPad across all domains? Or a limit per application on a domain?

i.e Could a mobile safari browser store e.g. 50MB for facebook.com and 50MB for spotify.com?

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as local storage: i.e., per domain. This is for web apps.

I'm less certain what would happen if you turned your site into a hybrid app with PhoneGap or Cordova, but suspect the limit would then be per app, since the domain would effectively be scoped to the app.